# iOS - Stopping UILocalNotification from outside the application

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

In my app, I'm able to set UILocalNotification successfully.

If my app is not running and if I want to stop those notifications, how can I cancel or delete them?

Is there any way to close or stop or delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use cancelAllLocalNotifications:

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Put it inside

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
```

Or in

```
 - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
```

if you wish to cancel them when your app is not active.

Or call it in any other timing.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. My app initiated UILocalNotification. User quits the app. (completely quit the app.) Now if the user wants to cancel or delete the local notification without open the app, how can the user do that?

Comment: He definetly can not delete them with out lunching your app. you can check (I truly don't know) if app preferences for notifications cancels local notifications too.